# Is there any way to take raw audio data from pyaudio and play it through javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, audio, pyaudio

Ok, so I want to have this program in python 2.5 with pyaudio that should record audio than send it to the server. What my program does is it records audio and than sends it to a online webpage that saves the most recent sound data sent. I want to have a javascript program that will play back that data to the speakers when a webpage is accessed. It will continuously access the server until the page is closed and it will play newly received sound data. I was about to make this, but than I realized I had no idea how to play the saved chunks of audio on the receiving webpage. Is there any way to do this? Thanks!